# Plotting with matplotlib does not give desired datetime format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

the data i used are derived from an excel file using `pd.read_excel`.

The objective: To plot DateTime vs Value with x axis values in the format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`.

The problem: The X axis format is not the desired `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`.

Below is a snippet of the code i used and its result. I am very new to programming in general and will really appreciate it if you guys can point me in the right direction!

```
>>> df.head()

            DateTime  Value
0 2016-05-17 22:50:27   1914
1 2016-05-17 22:55:27   1597
2 2016-05-17 23:00:27   1429
3 2016-05-17 23:05:27   1462
4 2016-05-17 23:10:27   2038

>>> df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

>>> df.plot(x='DateTime', y='Value')

>>> plt.show()
```

**Plot of DateTime vs Value:**
[image: Plot of DateTime vs Value]

Comment: can you try adding `import matplotlib.dates as dates
dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: It does not change anything. thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Sorry add this line at the end instead of `plt.show()` `formatter = dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
 plt.gcf().axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)`

Comment: It is now correct. thankyou. Does pd.to_datetime not do anything or am i using it wrong?

Comment: `to_datetime` converts strings to `datetime64` dtype, it doesn't affect formatting or display, that is something you need to do in matlplotlib. Alternatively what you can do is generate the strings and plot these but strings is less useful than real datetimes. So for instance `df['date_string'] = df['DateTime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` will give you a column of date strings

Comment: See updated answer on why using date strings as another method but the labels need to be rotated so they are readable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter) to achieve this:

```
import matplotlib.dates as dates
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df.plot(x='DateTime', y='Value')
formatter = dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
plt.gcf().axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

results in:

[image]

`to_datetime` converts strings to `datetime64` dtype, it doesn't affect the display in pandas or for matplotlib, so the correct method is above.

However, you could generate date strings using `dt.strftime` to add a column of desired date strings but this gives you a column of strings which is not as useful in my opinion:

```
In [39]:
df['DateStrings'] = df['DateTime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df

Out[39]:
             DateTime  Value          DateStrings
0 2016-05-17 22:50:27   1914  2016-05-17 22:50:27
1 2016-05-17 22:55:27   1597  2016-05-17 22:55:27
2 2016-05-17 23:00:27   1429  2016-05-17 23:00:27
3 2016-05-17 23:05:27   1462  2016-05-17 23:05:27
4 2016-05-17 23:10:27   2038  2016-05-17 23:10:27
```

this results in the plot:

```
df.plot(x='DateStrings', y='Value')
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can see though that the x-axis labels are duff, you'd need to rotate them which is handled automatically using the former method

Comment: Will read up more on data type conversion. Thanks for the detailed explanation.